# preventing reinserting of data when press browser's refresh button

Tags: asp.net

I developed a web application in asp.net.I have a module for saving values to database after clicking the button event.Thats working successfully.After that when i clicked the browser's refresh button the values reinserted to the table each time.How can i avoid this .Which is the code for this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice article on this

[Preventing Duplicate Record Insertion on Page Refresh](http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh)